# API Platform - How do I secure a single property of an entity?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

The documention of API platform states it's possible to secure on the  property level.

```
# api/config/api_platform/resources/Book.yaml
properties:
   App\Entity\Book:
        adminOnlyProperty:
            security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN")'
```

But, it's not working.

In operation level like documention says we can secure.

How do I secure only one field of an entity?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. "It's not working" is not a clear description of your problem. What error do you get? Please describe your problem a little more detailed.

Answer (score 2):

You can secure specific field by changing the serialization context dynamically using groups: [Changing the Serialization Context Dynamically](https://api-platform.com/docs/v2.7/core/serialization/#changing-the-serialization-context-dynamically)
This is the example provided by the docs:

```
<?php
// api/src/Entity/Book.php
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['book:output']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['book:input']],
)]
class Book
{
    // ...

    /**
     * This field can be managed only by an admin
     */
    #[Groups(['book:output', 'admin:input'])]
    public bool $active = false;

    /**
     * This field can be managed by any user
     */
    #[Groups(['book:output', 'book:input'])]
    public string $name;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using symfony custom constraints as mentioned here

https://smaine-milianni.medium.com/user-permission-and-symfony-validator-12b2c31d7817